# 64bit Dell stuck at login/splash screen

Tags: windows, boot, dell-inspiron, login-screen

**System:** Dell Inspiron 1110 64bit, Windows 7.

**Problem:** When booting it'll reach the login/splash screen. Well almost, it shows the blue windows 7 splash screen image, the mouse (with loading symbol for first few seconds), and nothing else. The mouse seems a little bit big/stretched, but I can still move it around.

The problem occurs if I try to boot normally, in safe mode, safe mode with networking or command prompt, boot from last known good configuration, or even Repair Your Computer.

#### Is there anything I can do?

---

Notes:

- I don't have a Windows boot disc.
- I don't think any of the keys are stuck.

---

**Update:**
Ran startup repair from a Windows recovery USB. Same problem happened after restart.

Comment: this sounds like what happened to me when my HD failed. Have you been having any SMART errors or problems with your HD lately?

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver Nope. I'm assuming you mean there would have been some alert/dialog detailing an error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 fails to start in any mode. What to do?](http://superuser.com/questions/316719/windows-7-fails-to-start-in-any-mode-what-to-do) and/or [Windows 7 stopped booting](http://superuser.com/questions/229487/windows-7-stopped-booting)

Answer (score 1):

Never assume you will get an alert.  Test your file system/hard drives; look into [tools such as SpinRite](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20spinrite), and check with Dell and (better) your HDD's manufacturer for diagnostics utilities specific to your drive.

As always, try to make a backup first.